# Translate Java code into Eclipse and Javac AST injection statements

Tags: java, reflection, abstract-syntax-tree, lombok

I am facing the following issue: I need to develop custom Lombok annotation handlers, and these handlers should inject quite complex methods into the objects. Since it's a research project, the content of the method is likely to change and I'm looking for a way to automate some manual tasks.

As well described in this [post](https://notatube.blogspot.fr/2010/12/project-lombok-creating-custom.html),  the greatest pain in the process of creating custom handlers is two implement twice, once for Eclipse and once for Javac, the AST injection code that add the method statements.

So my question is the following: are there any tools/projects around that  takes as input a Java file and the method name one wants to inject, and that outputs the Java code (for both Eclipse and Javac) that will insert this method into the handler ?

Comment: Why do you need to do this twice?  Why don't you run the "Lombok" process just once, where you can run it, and be done with it?

Comment: As I said, the code that I want to insert using annotation may vary a lot. I want to automate the procedure to generate the AST modification

Comment: Yes, I understood the point about AST modification.  You haven't explained why you want to implement the AST modification in two different places.

Comment: It's the lombok project, if you want to be able to use it within Eclipse that requires that you implement the AST modification in two places, namely Javac and Eclipse compiler.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a great reason to like lombok, when you have to do the work twice.   I thought I made it clear that you should look for another solution where you only have to do it once.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are going about this in an inconvenient way.  Based on what you are saying, you want a tool that will insert annotation-specific code where an annotation says to insert code.   You want to use Lombok, because it offers you the ability to write custom procedural hooks per annotation to hack at the AST.  You seem to be complaining about the inconvenience of writing such hooks.

If  you use a [Program Transformation System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) that has source-to-source transformations, you might be able to code those "hooks" in a non-procedural, easy to understand way.  Source to source transforms are expressed like this:

```
     if you see *thispattern*, replace it by *thatpattern*
```

(I build a program transformation system called DMS with these properties, see my bio).   A DMS source-to-source transformation to insert call logging for methods marked for logging might be:

```
    domain Java~v8;
    rule insert_call_logging(p: access_declarations,
                             t: type,
                             m: IDENTIFIER,
                             a: arguments,
                             s:statements):
                 method_declaration ->   method_declaration
    " @LogCalls \p \t \m(\a) { \b } "
      -> " \p \t \m(\a) { Log(\tostring\(\m\)); \b } ";
```

The *rule* **insert_call_logging** recognizes methods binding the metavariable **m** to the the method name, and binding other parts of the method to other meta variables.  The **"** are *metaquotes*, and help
the rule processor distinguish Java syntax from the rule language syntax.

What this rule does is look for a method that is specifically annotated **LogCalls**, and replace it by a method in which the annotation is gone, and a logging call with the text string for the method name (\tostring(\m)) has been inserted as the first statement in the method body.

Expressing the patterns directly means you don't have write a lot of custom code to climb up and down the syntax tree inspecting/changing the structure; that's pretty painful in practice because you have know way too much about the shape of the AST.

Including the annotation signal directly in the pattern
you don't have to attach your custom code to annotation processors;  the rule itself won't trigger unless the specific annotation  you expressed is present.

This rule may not be complicated enough, but you can write much more complex rules if you need to.  This can enable you to insert arbitarly complicated stuff, or change the code structure in arbitrarily complicated ways.

There are several PTS's out there, capable of doing this to varying degrees. (Arguably, Lombok is one of these on the weak end, since it does not do source-to-source transforms).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the experimental [lombok.ast](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok.ast) project.

It also has a parser for templates, where you can replace special nodes by any other ast.

It is experimental, and there's not a lot of documentation on how to use it. The owner of the github project might be able to help you.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.